# Mysql SELECT ... WHERE IN (multiple sub selects from multiple tables)

Tags: mysql

Mysql need to get data from one table, where ids is the same as column values in another table. But from the another table must get only column values, which ids are the same (`IN`) as column values in two other tables.

Tables are following:

Table name `sales_invoices` with columns (below i show not all columns, there are columns, that necessary for the question).
`IdInvoices` | `Date`

Table name `purchase_invoices` with columns
`IdInvoicesP` | `Date`

Table name `items` with columns
`IdI` | `IdGoodsServices` | `IdInvoices`

Table name `goods_services` with columns
`IdGs` (unique values)

Here are links among tables
`IdGs` = `IdGoodsServices`
 `IdInvoices` ( `items`) = `IdInvoices` (`sales_invoices`) = `IdInvoicesP`

Tried multiple variations of code. In all cases get errors. Below is the last used code.

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT `IdGs`) FROM `goods_services` WHERE `IdGs` IN 

  ( SELECT `IdGoodsServices` FROM `items` WHERE `IdInvoices` IN 

    ( SELECT `IdInvoices`, `IdInvoicesP` FROM 
    `sales_invoices`, `purchase_invoices` WHERE `Date` <= ? ) 

  )
```

Want to count `IdGs` (codes of products or goods/services) that contains in sales and purchase invoices, issued (written) until certain date.

There is no direct linking between `goods_services` and `sales_invoices` / `purchase_invoices`. Table `items` is linked to both `goods_services` and (`sales_invoices` / `purchase_invoices`)

With the code above get error
`SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'Date' in where clause is ambiguous`

Tried sub-sub select only from one table, get some result and no error.
Here is the query

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT `IdGs`) FROM `goods_services` WHERE `IdGs` IN 

  ( SELECT `IdGoodsServices` FROM `30u2s5r_items` WHERE `IdInvoices` IN 

    ( SELECT `IdInvoicesP` FROM 
    `30u2s5r_purchase_invoices` WHERE `Date` <= ? ) 

  )
```

Below is **working code** (as i tested until now).

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT `IdGs`) FROM `goods_services` WHERE `IdGs` IN 

 (SELECT `IdGoodsServices` FROM `items` WHERE 

 `IdInvoices` IN 

  (SELECT DISTINCT `IdInvoices` FROM `sales_invoices` 
  WHERE `sales_invoices`.`Date` <= ? ) 

   OR 

  `IdInvoices` IN 
  ( SELECT DISTINCT `IdInvoicesP` FROM `purchase_invoices` 
  WHERE `purchase_invoices`.`Date` <= ? ) 

)
```

Comment: @ShanteshwarInde Sorry, could not understand. Do you mean to create one more table or change name? How does it help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use purchase_invoices.Date or sales_invoices.Date

Comment: No... also get error `SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)` . Part of query `WHERE `invoices`.`Date` <= ? OR `purchase_invoices`.`Date` <= ? ` What is wrong?

Comment: No, you edited  query.In this case you must use 30u2s5r_purchase_invoices.Date.Also you don't need to use 30u2s5r_purchase_invoices before Date because  you get IdInvoicesP from one table

Comment: May be i do not understand something. But i need to get data also from `sales_invoices`. There may be possibility that in `sales_invoices` are some items that are not in `purchase_invoices`

Comment: ( SELECT `IdInvoices`, `IdInvoicesP` FROM 
    `sales_invoices`, `purchase_invoices` WHERE `Date` <= ? ) . Here you need to specify which table of dates you want to read from the table. like below ( SELECT IdInvoices, IdInvoicesP FROM sales_invoices, purchase_invoices WHERE sales_invoices.Date <= ? )

Comment: Want to read from both tables `sales_invoices` and `purchase_invoices`. But as understand it is impossible? Will get error. But if i read only from `sales_invoices`, there may be possibility, that in `purchase_invoices` will some `IdInvoicesP` which i do not select?

Comment: No, Because the two tables haven't relation with each other, you can write a query with two conditions like this : 
( SELECT `IdGoodsServices` FROM `items` WHERE `IdInvoices` IN 

    ( SELECT `IdInvoices` FROM 
    `sales_invoices` WHERE `Date` <= ? )
or `IdInvoices` IN 

    ( SELECT  `IdInvoicesP` FROM 
     `purchase_invoices` WHERE `Date` <= ? ) 

  )